# Using a GAE Endpoints object in a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm adding a simple web interface with the already working backend I wrote in Java for and Android app. I know there is a way for exposing GAE ednpoints to JS. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js

Instead I want the calls to the endpoint to be generated from a java servlet and pass them to a `JSP` so I initialise the `UserEndpoint` and call it's methods inside the `doGet()`.

Is there anything wrong with this method ?

Comment: The Java client library can be used from within a servlet context as well. The setup is a bit different, but it works.

Comment: How is the setup different ? Do you think it's worth it ?